Custom aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json Fails with "Exception During Build: Command Hooks Failed" for .NET 8 Application
I am deploying my .NET 8 application using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to a Windows IIS server. The deployment works fine when targeting the default IIS website. However, I want to deploy it to a custom website with a specific path, e.g., C:\App\TestMyApp.
To achieve this, I created a custom aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json file. Unfortunately, I encountered the following error during deployment:
Exception during build: Command hooks failed

Here is the aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json file I wrote:
   {
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "iisConfig": {
        "appPools": [
            {
                "name": "mytestapp",
                "recycling": {
                    "regularTimeInterval": 60
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "deployments": {
        "aspNetCoreWeb": [
            {
                "name": "app",
                "parameters": {
                    "appBundle": ".",
                    "appPool": "mytestapp",
                    "iisPath": "App/TestMyApp",
                    "iisWebSite": "mytestappweb"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

What I’ve Tried

Deploying to the default IIS website works without issues.
Checked the permissions of the Windows users running the deployment.

Notice issue

The custom path (C:\App\TestMyApp) is not being created on the server, which might be causing the issue.

Questions

Why is the custom path not being created on the server during deployment?
What additional steps or configurations are required to deploy the application to a -custom IIS website using AWS Elastic Beanstalk?
Are there logs or specific debug tools in AWS Elastic Beanstalk that can provide more details on the "Command hooks failed" error?

